# How to implement an editor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How does flutter implement an editor,
such as a code editor,
which controls can be used to implement it?

TextField is not appropriate?

Comment: Plain text edit box; 

Convenient for free editing; 

Shortcut key operation

Comment: You can try this package if it fulfill your requirements
https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor

Otherwise you can share the screenshot of your requirements